# 403 FORBIDDEN message when I use HttpPost to send data to Django

Tags: android, django, sqlite, http-post, http-status-code-403

I am trying to send data from android to Django app. I want to store the data in a table in sqlite database called "mytable". Here is the android code:

```
    try {
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8000/androidweb/edit/");
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
        try {
            j.put("name", "david");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year", j.toString()));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    //  myTextView.setText(j.toString());
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        myTextView.setText(response.getStatusLine().toString());
    //  myTextView.setText(response.toString());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        myTextView.setText("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
}
```

The issue is resolved now. I only needed to have a return value

Comment: None of your code should be generating a 403. What does the Django log look like?

Comment: Hey! How do you check the Django log? Could the error be because I am not returning anything from views.py?

Comment: If you're running the development server, look at the screen. Returning nothing would cause a 500.

Comment: Hey! I did as you said. The screen from Django returns "POST /androidweb/edit/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2326.

Comment: Put the project in debug mode and run it again.

Comment: I've run it in debug mode. Didn't really change the error. Should I be looking at something specific?

Comment: I would guess you need to add some authorization / authentication / cookie code, 403 forbidden probably exactly means that...

Comment: what it the django version ?, you might have to look at django csrf, http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

Comment: Hey! The Django version I am using is 1.2.3. I tried using the command @csrf_exempt, but I get the 500 internal server error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like Django's Cross-Site Request Forgery framework, which by default prevents third-party POST requests. Read Django's [CSRF docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/csrf/) for details.

Comment: Hey! I think you are right. I have downgraded to Django 1.1.1 to not have to deal with the csrf security measures. However, now I am getting 500 - internal server error. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: 500 errors are commonly due to errors in your code. If you weren't seeing them under Django 1.2 then I'd guess you may have something in your code that only works with Django 1.2 onwards - maybe you're importing a module or calling a method that didn't exist in 1.1? Your HTTP error logs should give you some clues.

Comment: yes you're right. must be something wrong in my code. I will figure it out